# Probaility of bruteforcing a four digit lock with and without memory

Tags: probability

I have a problem with a lock. The lock has a four digit code. The numbers span from 0 to 9 so the number of all possible combinations is $10^4$ I have 7200 guesses. And for now I can remember all of the codes I've inputted so far. What is my chance of finding the correct code?

My (probably incorrect) thought was that the chance of getting the correct one goes up after each wrong guess and since I have 7200 of these. I could simply add up an arithmetic sequence like this $\frac{7200}{2}\cdot(\frac{1}{10^4}+\frac{1}{(10^4)-7199})$ and get the probability. It equals 0.01285% in this case which just seems wrong.

And also I have the same problem but this time I don't remember which codes I've inputted and need to find out my probability of opening the lock this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem:

You are inputting $7200$ different codes. So the probability of one of them being the right code is exactly $$7200/10000=72\%$$

For the second problem:

At each attempt, the probability of failure is $9999/10000$. So for $7200$ attempts, the probability of failing each time is $(9999/10000)^{7200}$. So the probability of success is

$$1-(9999/10000)^{7200}\approx 51.33\%$$